# C# System.Type.GetType(string) returns nested class instead of the global class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, il2cpp

I have the following code structure as example:

```
public class Character {
    public enum MovementType {
    }
}

public class CombatMode {
    public class FinalFight {
        public class Character {
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is **System.Type.GetType("Character")** will return any Nested class named Character instead of global::Character.

Examples:

```
// This returns "Character, Assembly-CSharp, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" which is correct
string characterClassTypeName = typeof(global::Character).AssemblyQualifiedName;

// This will return the type CombatMode.FinalFight.Character and NOT global::Character like I would expect
System.Type.GetType(characterClassTypeName);
// Same with this
System.Type.GetType("Character");
// This returns null instead of the nested type Character.MovementType
System.Type.GetType("Character+MovementType");
// Same with this
System.Type.GetType(typeof(Character.MovementType).AssemblyQualifiedName);
```

What is the proper way to get the type global::Character from a string?

For context I am running this code in Unity 2021 TLS IL2CPP build. This issue does not occur in Unity editor or in Unity 2019 TLS IL2CPP build. So I am wondering if it is something with GetType I don't understand or maybe a new bug with IL2CPP?

Comment: Please add the Unity and IL2CPP tags as I'm 99.9% sure this will be a Unity/IL2CPP problem. My guess is that it's due to type rewriting in IL2CPP. Its certainly not just "normal" .NET behavior.

Comment: Yes sorry. At least this answer half of my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a IL2CPP bug which was [already reported](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/il2cpp-assembly-dot-gettype-returns-a-nested-class-when-the-nested-class-is-defined-before-the-non-nested-one), and it will be fixed in 2021.3.7.